# Why is $\left<u-P_mu,u_j\right>_V=0$ for $\left<.,.\right>_V=a(.,.) + t\left<.,.\right>_H$ and $a:V\times V\to\mathbb{R}$ a symmetric bilinear form

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, dual-spaces, bilinear-form

Let $V,H$ be Hilbert spaces with embedding $V\hookrightarrow H$ compact and $V$ dense in $H$. Let $a:V\times V\to\mathbb{R}$ be a symmetric, continuous bilinear form and define $A:V\to V'$ by $\left<Au,v\right> = a(u,v),u,v\in V$ with $\left<.,.\right>$ being the duality pairing between $V$ and its dual space $V'$. Define $\left<.,.\right>_V$ by

$$\left<u,v\right>_V = a(u,v) + t\left<u,v\right>_H$$

for a fixed $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Take it as granted that $\left<.,.\right>_V$ is an inner product on $V$ and suppose that $\{u_k\}_k$ is an orthonormal basis of $H$ such that $u_k$s are also eigenvectors of $A$ with corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_k$. Lastly, define $P_mu := \sum_{k=1}^m\left<u,u_k\right>_Hu_k$.

I am trying to understand why then $\left<u - P_mu,u_j\right>_V = 0$. That is, why

$$\left<u - P_mu,u_j\right>_V = \left<u,u_j\right>_V - \sum_{k=1}^m\left<u,u_k\right>_H\left(a(u_k,u_j) + t\left<u_k,u_j\right>_H\right)\leftrightarrow$$

$$\left<u - P_mu,u_j\right>_V = a(u,u_j) + t\left<u,u_j\right>_H - \sum_{k=1}^m\left<u,u_k\right>_H\left(\lambda_k\delta_k^j + t\delta_k^j\right)\leftrightarrow$$

$$\left<u - P_mu,u_j\right>_V = a(u,u_j) + t\left<u,u_j\right>_H - \left<u,u_j\right>_H\left(\lambda_j + t\right)\leftrightarrow$$

$$\left<u - P_mu,u_j\right>_V = a(u,u_j) - \lambda_j \left<u,u_j\right>_H = 0.$$

**Edit:** My exact question is the following: Why is $a(u,u_j) = \lambda_j \left<u,u_j\right>_H = 0$? By definition $a(u,u_j) = \left<Au,u_j\right> \equiv \left(Au\right)(u_j)$ as per the duality pairing. We know that $\lambda_j$ is an eigenvalue of $A^*$ but why would $u_j$ be an eigenvector of $A$ in the general  case that $A$ is an unbounded operators?

Comment: Looks like you are not applying the eigenvector property, which should read $a(u_j,v) = \lambda_j (u_j,v)_H$ for all $v\in V$.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand your post. What exactly is the question? Which step do you not understand? All these arrows should in fact be equality signs.

Comment: @daw Apologies for the inconvenience. I have now added my exact question. As I am writing this answer it occurs to me that as $a$ was assumed to be symmetric, $a(u,u_j) = a(u_j,u) = \lambda_j\left<u_j,u\right>_H$, which shows the equality.

Comment: Since $a$ is a continuous bilinear form, also $A$ is continuous and $A=A^*$.

Comment: @daw Nice observation! So the equality can be deduced in two ways. But then, doesn't the symmetricity argument show that continuity of $a$ is not needed in this particular case?